# URL hostname (https://example.com) of the configured OIDCRedirectURI does not match the URL hostname of the URL being accessed (https://test.com):

Tags: docker, apache, openid

I have created a docker image with the centos for the httpd and deployed the image to cloud foundry and CF deployed application is having the route as https://test.com and my redirect is https://example.com. When I try to hit the https://test.com from the browser I am getting the below error

URL hostname (https://example.com) of the configured OIDCRedirectURI does not match the URL hostname of the URL being accessed (https://test.com): the "state" and "session" cookies will not be shared between the two

Can someone please help me?

URL hostname (https://example.com) of the configured OIDCRedirectURI does not match the URL hostname of the URL being accessed (https://test.com): the "state" and "session" cookies will not be shared between the two